# Android MVP валидация во view

Tags: java, android, mvp

Скажите пожалуйста, допускается ли вариант валидации полей во view при использовании MVP подхода?
Поясню на примере: Есть форма входа с полями для логина и пароля, нужно провалидировать на заполенность полей и отобразить ошибку в случаи пустых полей. Эта логика должна быть реализованная в presenter или view?

Answer (score 2):

Логика валидации должна быть во Presentere,  нужно передать данные в презентер,  в презентере проверить данные и в зависимости от результата что-то делать (отобразить ошибку, либо продолжить авторизацию).
View - отвечает только за отображение данных.
Presenter - логика, взаимодействие View с Model